# How to de-allocate an array of characters in c?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that asks the number of strings which i'll then count how many spaces it has.
My problem is when I start a new cycle I can't allocate the array of characters I use to count the spaces.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char a[20];
    int x, z, esp=0, num;
    scanf("%d\n", &num);
    
    int array[num];
    
    for (int i=0;i<num;i++){
       
        scanf("%[^\n]", &a);
    
        z =strlen(a);
    
        for (x=0; x<=z; x++){
            if (a[x] == ' '){
            
                esp++;
            } 
        }
        array[i] = esp;
        esp =0;
        
    }
    
    for (int i=0;i<num;i++){
        printf ("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory that needs to be deallocated.

Comment: Note that the `%[]` format specifier expects an argument of type `char *`. You will get that from using plain `a` (which then *decay* to `&a[0]`). The type of `&a` is `char (*)[20]`. Mismatching format specifier and argument ype leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: "My problem is when I start a new cycle I can't allocate the array of characters" -- could you expand on this? What exactly happens?

Comment: remove `\n` from the first scanf format string

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

- Not having all warnings enabled.  Save time, enable them all.
- `'\n'` blocks for more input in `scanf("%d\n", &num);`
- Not checking `scanf()` return value.
- Not limiting input with a width in `scanf("%[^\n]", &a);`
- Wrong type passed in `scanf("%[^\n]", &a);`
- Big one: not consuming the end-of-line with repeated `scanf("%[^\n]", &a);` calls.
- Perhaps more.

Repaired code:

```
// scanf("%d\n", &num);
if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) {  // '\n' removed
  puts("Error1");
  return -1;
}


    // scanf("%[^\n]", &a);
    if (scanf(" %19[^\n]", a) != 1) {  // ' ' consumes white-space like \n
      puts("Error2");
      return -1;
    }
```

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for the suggested edit, yet OP's original code that needs  updating is at 2 different indentation levels.

Comment: "Not having all warnings enabled. Save time, enable them all. AND PAY ATTENTION TO THEM".

Comment: @pm100 True - true.  For learners, I suspect at least a third of the posts would have greatly benefited (perhaps OP would have even self solved) had OP "enabled all warnings" and  attempted to address them - sigh.

Comment: I think that -Wall -Werror should be the default. Once somebody gets more experienced, they will work out how to and when to turn that down, but that horse left the stable a long time ago

Answer (score 0):

On the first scanf, remove \n character, after the first scanf, add getchar() to consume new line character.
Replace second scanf with gets;

Then it will work correctly.

By the way, since gets is unsafe, you can use fgets with stdin parameter and max character count parameter instead of gets.

Comment: "Replace second scanf with gets;" --> `gets()` is no longer part of the Standard C library since 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who commented and answered my question, I think I wasn't able to explain myself properly. It's a code which reads a number, the number of the lines of characters which then it'll count the spaces of;  my problem started when the code executes a new cycle in which this `scanf` didn't let me enter the string of characters again: `scanf("%[^\n]", &a)`, but did everything else in the cycle while using the same string.
I'm really new to this, coding and the page itself so thanks for the advices. I was able to find a solution: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c, &a)`

- %*[^\n] scans everything until a `\n`, but doesn't scan in the `\n`. The asterisk(`*`) tells it to discard whatever was scanned.
- `%*c` scans a single character, which will be the `\n` left over by `%*[^\n]` in this case. The asterisk instructs scanf to discard the scanned character.

And here is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char a[20];
    int x, z, esp=0, num;
    scanf("%d\n", &num);
    
    int array[num];
    
    for (int i=0;i<num;i++){
       
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &a);
    
        z =strlen(a);
    
        for (x=0; x<=z; x++){
            if (a[x] == ' '){
            
                esp++;
            } 
        }
        array[i] = esp;
        esp =0;
        
    }
    
    for (int i=0;i<num;i++){
        printf ("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
return 0;
}
```